# Depended output based on caller

Tags: python, secret-key

I have following class with a property:

```py
class ClassWithSecrets:
    def __init__(self, secret):
        self._secret = secret

    @property
    def secret(self):
        # PSEUDO SECTION #
        if caller is print or higher than logger.DEBUG:
             raise error
        # PSEUDO END #
        return self.secret
```

In the Pseudo section I want to raise an error if the `getter` is called from print any higher level as DEBUG. I know about inspect, but also read that inspect should not be used in production.

The Idea is to ensure, that I and my fellow developers are stopped using print or logging above DEBUG level, if using this property. I am aware, that someone can change the property if access to the code, but hopefully this is prevented from a senior in merge request.

Is what I want to achieve possible?

Comment: You probably can do something with `inspect` module, but what is the point? This looks like XY problem. Note that everyone that has access to source code can change that behaviour and compromise your `secret`, i.e. this is not secure implementation

Comment: The secret is provided at runtime after password authentication. I've edited the question to clarify my problem.

Comment: `print(yourfunc())` does not make `print` the caller, so I don't know that you expect this to accomplish. `x = yourfunc(); print(x)` as two separate statements will moreover defeat any analysis of the stack to see if the calling line invokes `print()`.

Comment: Also, a caller can just obfuscate their code a little if they choose. `sys.stderr.write()` instead of `print()`, or `os.write(2, ...)`, or a POST to a pastebin, etc. You can't write code to recognize every possible mechanism to exfil data.

Comment: To be clear: is stack analysis technically possible? Yes. Is stack analysis that's going to be actually effective at preventing exfil feasible in practice given a remotely competent attacker? Not at all. And our scope is limited to _practical, answerable_ questions: if something isn't useful in practice it's off topic here.

Comment: Also... you realize someone can ignore the property and access `_secret` directly, right?

Comment: _The Idea is to ensure, that I and my fellow developers are stopped using print or logging above DEBUG level, if using this property._  - it is still unclear what the benefit is. i.e. assuming anyone can run with it DEBUG level. Who do you want to keep from exposing `secret` - developers, end-users? If it is really developers - they should presumably work with test/dummy data anyway

Comment: @Charles Duffy Yes I am aware of no real private structure in python, and also that are other methods to bypass what I want to achieve.

Comment: @buran I hope for following benefit: I tend to use print() as a fast but bad debugging solution, like probably many do. With my attempt I want at least ensure the developer recognize the bad habit me including.

Comment: That's even bigger non-sense if the idea is not to protect the `secret` but enforce coding-style. That is what the code review is for.

Comment: You could make it at least a little harder on attackers by closing over a local or hiding it in a C module; using a property is not even trying. But regardless -- the analysis required isn't feasible; doing it comprehensively, if even possible, is something people would spend years trying to implement well (and closing up holes if attackers are kind enough to publish them), far too broad to fit in a SO answer. Yes, we could build a toy implementation that works in exactly one case, but that toy would be useless in practice.

Comment: @buran I don't want to start a discussion if enforcing coding-style should only happens at code review. Rust is doing kind of similar with the strict compiler and teaches the while compiling. My Idea why not achieve something for secret which are handled in development.

Comment: @Charles Duffy from your comment I estimate that handling a decoded-at-runtime-secret is not a good idea to safe into a class property which needs access to the secret. Can you provide a hint why and what to do against it?

Comment: @MaKaNu, it's not so much the property itself but the attribute that backs it that's a risk. Consider redefining the property itself when the secret is loaded, instead of changing an attribute it refers to -- a half-competent reverse engineer with arbitrary code execution will still be able to extract the secret (f/e, by using the `ast` and/or `dis` modules), but at least you make things harder for the complete incompetents that way.

Comment: How can an attacker extract the secret, since it is encrypted with a user password provided to the code via file only at runtime? The Secret is an API-Key which at the moment isn't possible to receive from the server via Authentication. So we register the API-Key with user specific passwords.